# Display Drive on MacBook Running Debian Sid

Tags: debian, drivers, display, macintosh

I'm trying to revive a very old macbook (2011) by installing Debian Sid on it. The install completed fine but on start the system would hang. I eventually got around this by setting `nomodeset` in grub.

The system now boots but the display resolution is low and the display will not turn on after the system has been put to sleep and woken up. Searching the web it seems like it might be because I'm using the Intel display drivers.

So I made sure `firmware-linux-nonfree` and `firmware-amd-graphics` were installed and rebooted. After the reboot the resolution was still off. Running `lshw -c video` shows that the display is unclaimed. The web suggests this is because of the `nomodeset` in grub but removing that still results in a hang on boot.

Any ideas at what to do next? I'd like to somehow try an load the AMD driver once the system is booted but I'm not sure that's possible.

Any and all help/comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of searching I've come to the conclusion that the AMD graphics chip in the MacBook Pro just doesn't work with Linux. So instead I've followed the guide [here](https://orville.thebennettproject.com/articles/installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-a-2011-macbook-pro/) to disable it and use the integrated Intel graphics and everything now works fine.